# Adding Space into Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have added an recyclerview and floating action button in an activity where each item of recyclerview has some UI elements.Atlast of its item UI cannot be accessedbecause it is getting covered by floating button how to make space only for last item so that it should not be covered by floating action and eligible to access.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.packtpub.ups.customer.Second"
android:background="#DCDCDC">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/nextToThird"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorgreen"
    android:src="@drawable/right"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my item container.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttons">

<Button android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/accept"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:background="@drawable/scan_button"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:text="@string/Accept"/>

<Button android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/decline"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:background="@drawable/scan_button"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:text="@string/Decline"/>

    <Button android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewmode"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:background="@drawable/scan_button"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:text="@string/Viewmode"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below line in RecyclerView tag in xml,

```
 android:paddingBottom="85dp"
 android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in adapter

```
 if (position == list.size()-1)
 {
     viewHolder.setPadding(150,0,0,0);
 }
```